# Explain all moves in Optaplanner

Tags: java, kotlin, optaplanner

I'm currently using `ObservabilityPhaseListener` to hook into the optimization runs. A specific use-case is to debug why a certain combination/move lead to a lower score (and so did not get selected).

Currently, `stepEnded` is the lowest I can go, but it's already too late since a "bad" move will not be selected and as such never explained.

I've also been using a hack, to perform a move in `stepEnded` and explaining it, but it's sometimes not feasible or simply too much effort.

Does anyone have an idea on how to accomplish explaining all moves (and their poor scores) as an optimization proceeds?

Thanks.

--
edit: I've managed to implement a custom `ScoreDirectoryFactory` but having problems plugging it in the config:

```
class MyScoreDirectorFactory<Solution_>(solutionDescriptor: SolutionDescriptor<Solution_>?, kieContainer: KieContainer?, ksessionName: String?) : DroolsScoreDirectorFactory<Solution_>(solutionDescriptor, kieContainer, ksessionName) {
    @Override
    override fun buildScoreDirector(lookUpEnabled: Boolean, constraintMatchEnabledPreference: Boolean): DroolsScoreDirector<Solution_> {
        return super.buildScoreDirector(lookUpEnabled, true)
    }
}

val config = SolverConfig().apply {
        environmentMode = REPRODUCIBLE
        solutionClass = XYZ::class.java
        entityClassList = listOf(...)

        scoreDirectorFactoryConfig = ScoreDirectorFactoryConfig().apply {
             ... // ?
        }
}
```

Comment: "A specific use-case is to debug why a certain combination/move lead to a lower score (and so did not get selected)." Can you copy paste the relevant TRACE log lines, both of the move evaluations and the selected step following those, to prove that? Because that sounds like a bug, if that's the case.

Comment: Maybe I can clear that up, so OptaPlanner behaves as expected, but humans would often ask why a certain combination was rejected and that's where the broken constraints can come in handy

Answer (score 2):

> humans would often ask why a certain combination was rejected and that's where the broken constraints can come in handy

Let the users make changes in the UI and run the result through `ScoreManager.explain(Solution)` to display the Score and [a heat map of the Indictments](https://www.optaplanner.org/blog/2017/03/13/VisualizeTheScoreAndTheConstraints.html).

Comment: We're working on this, so far it was not easily possible to have the changes made to an input statement that easily (since some metadata was being initialized as part of Construction Heuristic). Additionally, certain moves touch an entity several times in the process of optimization and I was merely curious, if this can be simply hooked into without the need to "create" multiple input permutations.

Thanks, seems we've exhausted all possible solutions.

Comment: Not the instances themselves, but using the strategy oh initializing the `Solution` then running explain on it that yields the string.

Answer (score 1):

For what's it worth (here be dragons!):

Turn on `TRACE` logging to identify which step index and which move index in that step don't behave like you expect.
Put a conditional breakpoint in the `LocalSearchDecider` with the condition that the step index and move index match (to skip the thousands of move evaluations before you hit that break point). In there, run a code fragment using `ScoreManager.explainScore()` before and after the move is done (before it is undone).

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! I am actively looking for dragons now :)

I failed to mention that I have tried that approach before and got 
`When constraintMatchEnabled (false) is disabled in the constructor, this method should not be called.` error. Probably since we're not using Simple scoring

I was unable to find a way to circumvent it but if there's a way, all the proverbial dragons would be put to rest.

Comment: If you're hacking anyway, hack the `ScoreDirectorFactory`'s, such as `DroolsScoreDirectorFactory`, their `buildScoreDirector()` method to ignore `boolean constraintMatchEnabledPreference` and just pass `true` instead.

Comment: I managed to implement a custom ScoreDirectorFactory, but not sure how to use it in my dynamic (kotlin) config. Updated the question with details.

Comment: That won't be possible, to inject a custom ScoreDirectorFactory, I thought you were building from source. In any case, here be dragons - this is so far away from normal usage patterns, that I doubt this is a good path to continue to follow. The more important question is: why do you want/need to do all these hacks and what kind of RFE in OptaPlanner out-of-the-box could help you with your original problem?

Comment: The use case is, while during vehicle route planning, often it is asked - why wasn't X picked up before Y and it would be nice to know which of the constraints were violated when a move was performed putting X before Y (there are enough steps so I can see in trace the move was performed)